# Haskell type class and initial algebra

Tags: haskell

For the example below, I am trying to understand how Haskell type classes, type class instances, and data types relate to the concept of [initial algebra](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Initial_algebra).
There are two Haskell data types sharing a pair of operations for equality and addition. From my, perhaps incorrect, understanding the instances, which include the data types, specify two non-isomorphic initial algebras.
It seems to me that the type class permits the overloading of the operations and plays no role in the specification of the initial algebra.
Is this a correct interpretation of the given example?

```
data Nat0 = Zero | Succ0 Nat0 deriving Show
data Nat1 = One | Succ1 Nat1 deriving Show

class PeanoNum n where
 eq :: n -> n -> Bool
 add :: n -> n -> n

-- Two different non-isomorphic algebras.
instance PeanoNum Nat0 where
 eq Zero Zero = True 
 eq (Succ0 m) (Succ0 n) = eq m n
 eq _ _  = False 
 add m Zero = m 
 add m (Succ0 n) = Succ0 (add m n) 


instance PeanoNum Nat1 where
 eq One One = True
 eq (Succ1 m) (Succ1 n) = eq m n
 eq _ _ = False
 add m One = Succ1 m
 add m (Succ1 n) = Succ1 (add m n)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** we can show that they are in fact isomorphic. Defining two different instances over them does not make them different. Defining two different functions over two types does not make them non-isomorphic! The instances are not describing an initial algebra structure, the `data` keyword is. As you say, the two instances play no role in the specification of the initial algebra.

---

In our example, we work with algebras
for the functor $1 + -$. That is, an algebra $A$ is given by a morphism $1 + A \to A$, or, in other words, an *element* of type $A$, which can be seen as a morphism $1 \to A$, and an *endomorphism* $A \to A$.

```
data Nat0 = Zero | Succ0 Nat0
data Nat1 = One | Succ1 Nat1
```

Here, `Zero` and `One` are the elements while `Succ0` and `Succ1` are the endomorphisms. We will see that they are isomorphic as F-algebras. A morphism $f$ between two F-algebras $A$ (with element $a$ and endomorphism $u$) and $B$ (with element $b$ and endomorphism $v$) is a $f \colon A \to B$ making the following diagram commute.

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
A+1     @>f+1>>  B+1\\
@VVa+uV        @VVb + vV\\
A    @>f>>  B
\end{CD}$$

And, in fact, *we can find a pair of invertible morphisms making them isomorphic*.
I will only define the first one, but the second one is analogous and checking that they are inverses should be easy.

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\mathsf{Nat0}+1     @>f+1>>  \mathsf{Nat1}+1\\
@VV\mathsf{Zero+Succ0}V        @VV\mathsf{One + Succ1}V\\
\mathsf{Nat0}     @>f>>  \mathsf{Nat1}
\end{CD}$$

The commutativity of the diagram determines that the only possible $f$ must send `Zero` to `One` and `Succ0 x` to `Succ1 x`. This translates into code as follows.

```
f :: Nat0 -> Nat1
f Zero = One
f (Succ0 x) = Succ1 x
```

Precisely because $A$ is initial, this is the only possible $f$ making this diagram commute. We had no choice when defining $f$ (apart from `undefined` or any other of the constructions that make this kind of categorical reasoning fail in Haskell).

**What about the two instances?** They define two different functions over each one of the types, but that does not make them non-isomorphic as algebras. As you say, the instances play no role on the definition of the two algebras. The algebra structure concerns only the $1+A \to A$ morphism, not the two additional morphisms $A \times A \to A$ and $A \times A \to \mathsf{Bool}$ that define the instance. Even if we call the two different functions `add`, the second one is simply a different function. We could rename the second `add`, and we would see that they are, essentially, two different instances of the same class for (essentially) the same type.

**What if we want an "add" (a binary) function to be part of the algebra?** Then we would be looking for the initial algebra for the functor $F(X) = 1 + X + X \times X$, and neither `Nat0` nor `Nat1` (with their respective `add` functions) are *initial* algebras for this functor. The initial algebra would be the following one.

```
data Foo = Zero | Succ Foo | Add Foo Foo
```

**What if we also want an "equality" function to be part of the algebra?** There may be a better approach for this, but we can consider algebras on the category whose objects are *pairs* of types. An algebra is of the form $F(A,B) \to (A,B)$ for some endofunctor $F$, and in this case, we consider algebras of the form $(1 + A + A \times A, A \times A) \to (A,B)$. The natural numbers ($A$) and the booleans ($B$) endowed with zero $1 \to A$, the successor function $A \to A$, addition $A \times A \to A$, and the equality function $A \times A \to B$ would be *an* algebra of this form, but not *the* initial algebra. I think the initial algebra in this case could be written in Haskell as follows.

```
-- Initial algebra (where the object is a pair of types!).
data A = Zero | Succ A | Add A A
data B = Equ A A

-- Given any other algebra.
data C
data D
z :: C
s :: C -> C
a :: C -> C -> C
e :: C -> C -> D

-- There is a unique morphism (two morphisms) from the initial
-- algebra making the relevant diagram commute.
u1 :: A -> C
u1 Zero = z
u1 (Succ x) = s (u1 x)
u1 (Add x y) = a (u1 x) (u1 y)

u2 :: B -> D
u2 (Equ x y) = e (u1 x) (u1 y)
```

Where the relevant diagram is the following one.

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
(1+A+A\times A,A \times A)    @>>>  (1+C+C\times C,C \times C)\\
@V(Zero+Succ+Add,Equ)VV        @VV(z+s+a,e)V\\
(A,B)    @>(u1,u2)>>  (C,D)
\end{CD}$$

Comment: Thanks for your clear and informative answer. I mistakenly thought that the class instance defined the initial algebra.

Comment: Is it possible to add equality or does that lead to a multi-sort algebra?

Comment: I have edited the answer to provide a possible solution in which we consider an algebra over the category of "pairs" of types and "pairs" of morphisms between them.

Comment: The typical way to address multiple sorts is to consider initial algebras in $\mathbf{Set}^S$ where $S$ is the set of sorts (viewed as a discrete category if you want to view this as functor category, or it could directly be viewed as a [power](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power)). For $|S|=2$, this indeed leads to a category equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}\times\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @Mario My current understanding is that an algebra is defined by the constructors in a *data* statement. What then do the equations in an *instance*  define? Is it a different algebra?

Comment: Yes, and the algebra induced by the constructors in a *data* statement is initial; inductive types are initial algebras. Typeclasses, however, do not induce *in general* an algebra. You could use them to check that a morphism $FA \to A$ exists and in that case, any instance would be describing an algebra structure; but they do not necessarily fit that pattern in general.